# Why it give the error "initialize variable image"? But when I initialize the app crash

Tags: java, android, imageview

This is the second class, that gives the format to the images I`m using

```
public ViewPagerAdapter(Activity activity, String[] images) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.images = images;


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view==object;
}


@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater =(LayoutInflater)activity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item,container,false);

    ImageView image;
    DisplayMetrics dis = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dis);
    int height = dis.heightPixels;
    int width = dis.widthPixels;
    image.setMinimumHeight(height);
    image.setMinimumWidth(width);

    try {
        Picasso.with(activity.getApplicationContext())
                .load(images[position])
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(image);

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    container.addView(itemView);
    return itemView;


}

@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View)object);
}}`
```

and this is the primary class

```
    ViewPager viewPager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
private String [] images = {




};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(Search.this,images);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);




}}
```

I`m following this youtube tutorial, and I have the same code but mine doesn't work https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SX8l9vv-N_4
it if forces me to declare the variable as null, but in the video doesn't.

Comment: In your code, I don't see you initialize the image view ?
ImageView image = new ImageView(context);

Comment: Because you did not initialize `image` So its clearly a NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget findViewById `image = findViewById(...);`

Comment: even if it's a secondary class that manage the design its necessary?

Comment: yes, you need initial for imageView.